# Best practice to backup EC2 Instance Files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, backup, smb

I'm new to AWS Platform and its EC2 mechanisms.
I have an Instance running Ubuntu Server with a service that creates backups every night.

Since my service can store the backup on an FTP server or to an SMB share, I wondering if it is possible to use the SMB protocol to store the backup into S3.

In the past I used BOTO (for python) to access to S3 bucker. But since this backup are very precious, I looking for a well tested mechanism to store the backup into S3.

Currently, I use "Data Lifecycle Manager" to make a backup of my instance every night.
In this way I use a lot of space (around 8 Gb) to backup few files (around 200 Mb) and spend money.

I'm looking for a better way to make backups.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: How about just a cron job that uses the AWS CLI command to copy the files to S3? Why do you need SMB protocol for this?

Comment: I tought to the SMB protocol just because my service has the backup on SMB as built-in functionality

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so, please accept it/upvote it

Answer (score 0):

> if it is possible to use the SMB protocol to store the backup into S3.

You can use a [File Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/filegateway/latest/files3/what-is-file-s3.html). If your Ubuntu server is running on EC2, then you can configure the [gateway to run on EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/file-gateway-ec2/).

Comment: the file gateway requires another EC2 Instance? Thanks

Comment: @Federico if your Ubuntu server is on premise, then the file gateway should be on premise too. If your Ubuntu server is on EC2, then the file gateway should be on EC2 too

Comment: Yes I understand, but I would like to know if FileGateway service runs on a dedicated Instance. Just to understand the costs. My EC2 Instance is running on Cloud.

Comment: @Federico Yes, it requires its own dedicated instance.